# spring cloud stream kafka consumer clientId anonymous

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am new  to kafka  with  spring  cloud stream.the  application  is in two  in  one.
the  first application  is producing  to kafka topic (com.ng.vela.even.card_verified) which  is very accurate but the second one is give me the  following in my console but messages are not being comsumed from the  kafka topic.

This  is what  am  getting  in my console .

```
 020-06-24 14:36:07.168  INFO 7784 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9-24, groupId=anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9] Successfully joined group with generation 1
    2020-06-24 14:36:07.170  INFO 7784 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9-24, groupId=anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9] Adding newly assigned partitions: com.ng.vela.even.card_verified-0
    2020-06-24 14:36:07.171  INFO 7784 --- [  restartedMain] .ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener : Condition evaluation unchanged
    2020-06-24 14:36:07.171  INFO 7784 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9-24, groupId=anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9] Found no committed offset for partition com.ng.vela.even.card_verified-0
    2020-06-24 14:36:07.173  INFO 7784 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9-24, groupId=anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9] Found no committed offset for partition com.ng.vela.even.card_verified-0
    2020-06-24 14:36:07.180  INFO 7784 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9-24, groupId=anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9] Resetting offset for partition com.ng.vela.even.card_verified-0 to offset 63.
    2020-06-24 14:36:07.183  INFO 7784 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.b.k.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$1  : anonymous.1bf08674-d2fd-447a-b7d6-ce0c9eb597e9: partitions assigned: [com.ng.vela.even.card_verified-0]
```

the java source  code  is this below cos I am trying to follow  the documentation of spring cloud stream :

```java
    package com.mint.financial;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
    import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
    import com.mint.financial.entity.CardSchemeStream;
    import com.mint.financial.kafka.consumer.CardSchemeKafkaConsumer;
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableBinding(Processor.class)
    public class MintFinancialClientConsumerApplication {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(MintFinancialClientConsumerApplication.class, args);
        }
         @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
         @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
        public String handle(String value) {
            System.out.println("Received: " + value);
            return value ;
        }
        @Bean
       public CardSchemeStream getCardSchemeStream() {
            return new CardSchemeStream() ;
        }
        @Bean
        public ApplicationRunner initializeConnection(){
            return args -> {
                 System.out.println("handler testing for api working also with application runner");
            };
        }
    }
```

The  pom  is

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.mint</groupId>
        <artifactId>MintFinance</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>MintFinancialClientConsumer</name>
        <description>Visa Validation project Consumer for  mint financial technology</description>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>  
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

The  application.properties  file  is

```
    spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
    spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
    spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
    spring.data.mongodb.database=mint
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binders.broker=9092
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=2181
    spring.cloud.stream.input.group.name=test-consumer-group
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=com.ng.vela.even.card_verified
  spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=com.ng.vela.even.card_verified
    #spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=first-topic
    #spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=first-topic
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionCount=1
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=text/plain
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.headerMode=headers
```

As shown above, every other thing is working  including the connection to  mongodb
but  i cant just consume  messages that  i have  produced  to kafka.I am trying to produce and consume from the same  topic.
I have  even  considered using the default consumer group due to the  error, but all to  no  avail.
Again,I changed the  replication factor in server.properties file to  3  but yet nothing  is working.
I  have searched  everywhere . please guys i need your help .

Comment: Consuming from and producing to the same topic makes no sense. Are you sure there are records in that topic? Add property `logging.level.org.springframework.kakfa=debug` to see topic polling acivity.

Comment: are you  saying i  cant  use  the  same for producing  and  consuming ? there  are messages  there . yes  there  are  records there. ok let  me try  add it to  my application.properties  file  now and  see

Comment: but gary , is  my code above  expected to  work ? pls what should  i  do  ?

Comment: I have  tried this  but still ,it is  not showning any  polling activity and  neither is  it consuming any  messages.

Comment: Of course you can consume and produce in the same application; it just doesn't make sense to send the consumed value back to the same topic; it will loop forever.

Comment: let  me refactor  my code and i will get  back soonest. i appreciate gary.